# WooCommerce - How to add column to product list in admin order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to add a column product list to admin order page.
Something like on the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of WooCommerce, there's no easy way.

This is the code responsible for that part.

```
    <tbody id="order_line_items">
    <?php
        foreach ( $line_items as $item_id => $item ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_item_' . $item->get_type() . '_html', $item_id, $item, $order );

            include( 'html-order-item.php' );

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_' . $item->get_type() . '_html', $item_id, $item, $order );
        }
        do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_items_after_line_items', $order->get_id() );
    ?>
    </tbody>
```

Specifically this line: `include( 'html-order-item.php' );`.
Of which if you take a look at the contents of `html-order-item.php`, there's no hook for you to able to add another `td`.

What I can suggest though is you use one of the two actions above inside `foreach` loop. Use it to place a `td` tag with your data.
Then use jQuery to transfer that `td` to where it should be.

Comment: It's not a problem for me to edit the plugin core files, so I'll do that in html-order-item.php Thanks

Comment: @user3013821 that should be a problem and at all cost must be avoided.. but it's your call.. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() {
    $column_name = 'TEXT';
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {

    $value = 50;
if($item['type']=="line_item")
     echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: The column does however appear randomly after "cost of goods" and not at the end after "Total" on the line item. Still trying to figure out how I can move.